# Angular 2 way of doing options[elt.selectedIndex].text

Tags: angular

Assuming I have selected an option from  element, with pure JavaScript I would do something like:

```js
var elt = document.getElementById('e') as HTMLSelectElement;
if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
  return null;

return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
```

html is:

```html
<select id="e" #e>
  <option value="1">One</option> 
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Now with angular 6, I tried:

```js
@ViewChild('e') e: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.e.nativeElement.text)
}
```

What would be the equivalent in Angular 2? I tried `ElementRef` with `nativeElement.text` but it is `undefined`.

Comment: Please include your angular version of code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dropdown-njnodm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: You can also use `this.e.nativeElement.selectedOptions[0].text`. Or get the text in the `onChange` event handler, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dropdown-qdbtdu).

Comment: Thanks @yurzui that work well and ConnorsFan too. Can you answer so I select it as as answer?

Comment: @ConnorsFan totally unrelated but just in case I need it....what if the element was in a child component?

Comment: The child component could use an `EventEmitter` to notify the parent that a change occurred. I don't know if that is what you were thinking about. I have a question of my own: do you use the option values? If not, the code could be much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `this.select.nativeElement.value` to get the value of selected element. Also note the usage of `HTMLSelectElement` instead of `ElementRef`

```html
<select #select (change)="onChange()">    
  <option value ="1">one</option>
  <option value ="2">two</option>
  <option value ="3">three</option>
</select>
```

```js
@ViewChild('select') select : HTMLSelectElement;

onChange() {
  console.log(this.select.nativeElement.value)
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-dropdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Amit...but that returns "1", instead of one. I need the text value of the selected option, not its value

Comment: Check the elements children for which has the value "1"

Comment: I am not sure if there is a direct way to fetch it, but you can definitely loop through your options array and get the text.

Comment: I do that currently but was thinking there may be a different way. Thanks still guys.

Comment: Check @yurzui 's demo in comments.. That's a nice way to fetch it.